# onclick event is not working 

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
<div id="searchBox">
    <form role="search" method="get" name="searchform" id="searchform" action="http://websoftnet.com/projects/healthlink/" >
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Search.." onclick="make_blank();">
        <id="searchsubmit" onClick="document.searchform.submit();return false;"/>
    </form>
```

onclick event is not working

Comment: 1) that looks like JavaScript - not PHP , 2) that also looks like malformed HTML (`< id>` is not a valid element) - maybe that's the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The less source code to give an appropiate answer.

Comment: why are the downvotes?Everyone can make mistakes..

Comment: @BurnAfterReading Note [revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6200881/1), and a (still present) lack of an actual question - "this is my code, it's broken, read my mind and fix it"; hence "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: @Piskvor thanks for the explanation Mr.Piskvor.I guess I missed the revision.And I think people should take back their downvotes after revisions.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" />` (a form submit button)
instead of this thing: `<id="searchsubmit" onClick="document.searchform.submit();return false;"/>` (not a valid HTML element).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with PHP - rather HTML and JS.

Your problem is that it's not valid HTML in the first place. Depending on what you're trying to do, you'll need to use an `<input>` or `<a>`.